# how to change mysql query to laravel 5.5 and show it in view blade

Tags: php, laravel

i want to change this sql query to laravel 5.5 and show it to blade php

```
$sql_rsk_down = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM data_ap WHERE AP_NAME LIKE 'RSK%' AND STATUS LIKE '%DOWN%'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$count = DB::table('data_ap')
         ->where('AP_NAME','like','RSK%')
         ->where('STATUS','like','%DOWN%')
         ->count();

return view('your_blade', compact('count'));
```

Comment: many thanks, how if i using function "NOT LIKE", because when i use not like thats not function..

Comment: `->where('STATUS','not like','%DOWN%')` for example.